# Why do services need recycling?

Tags: windows, service, deadlock

I have seen that most services on windows needs recyling and infact we have automated recycling many process. Why does this happen? are there any commonly known areas where windows services get stuck?

I am writing a windows service and needs to know which places in programming are prone to this ?

I could figure for eg. file move operations ? what else could cause this and how can we avoid this? are they just deadlocks?

Comment: Sounds to me like there's something wrong with your computer.

Answer (score 2):

Services *shouldn't* need recycling. Poorly written services might not be able to recover from temporal issues, such as a remote server being rebooted; or if they leak resources; or fragment their memory space. If you're writing your own services, then you should watch out for those at the very least or perform diagnostics as to why they need restarting.